# Vuejs not passing property to mounted

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-router, computed-properties

Have the following code:

```js
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/noticia/:id',
      name: 'Noticia',
      component: Noticia,
      props: true
    }
  ]
})
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'Noticia',
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  props: ['id'],
  computed: {
    noticia () {
      return this.$store.getters.noticia
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      console.log(id)
      // Code that will run only after the
      // entire view has been rendered
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<div>{{id}}</div>
```

The problem is {{id}} is showed by html div, but it isn't passed to 'mounted', so, i cannot run my 'console.log(id)' (as it will run a code to bring data and put it into the computed).

I have other code running with the same data, running wheel, cannot understand the error

Comment: try `data () {
    return {id: null}
  }`

Comment: In mounted() you should use: this.id

Comment: Worked with this.id

Answer (score 1):

```
mounted() {
   console.log( this.id )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it working on mounted, just did:

this.id instead of just id